# Problem with RSolve function

Tags: equation-solving, difference-equations

When I use RSolve to solve the recurrence: $S(n)=\dfrac{1}{-S(n-1)-2},S(1)=-2/3$, it gives an empty solution:

[image]

however the solution should be:$S(n)=-\dfrac{n+1}{n+2}$

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: `FindSequenceFunction[ RecurrenceTable[{s[n] == 1/(-2 - s[n - 1]), s[1] == -2/3}, 
  s, {n, 1, 10}], n]` finds the solution  $-(n+1)/(n+2)`.

Comment: @kglr I know this method, but how Mathematica gives an empty solution?

Comment: Because,Mathematica is not a **magic box** that'll spit out a solution to any problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a "feature" of `RSolve[]`. Notice the following code

```
RSolve[{s[n] == 1/(-2 - s[n - 1])}, s[n], n] // Simplify
```

returns `{{s[n] -> -1}}` and this **does** satisfy the recursion equation, but not  the intial condition which is why it returned no solutions in your attempt. However, as you found out, there is a parametrized family of solutions given by

```
s[ n_] := -(n + k)/(n + k + 1);
```

which apparently `RSolve` does **not** find. You should be aware that the capabilities of `RSolve` and other `*Solve` functions are limited and subject to change. Perhaps in a later version of `Mathematica` it will be able to find this family of solutions.

Also, as user 'kgir' mentioned in a comment, it is possible to use

```
FindSequenceFunction[ RecurrenceTable[
  {s[n] == 1/(-2 - s[n - 1]), s[1] == -2/3}, s, {n, 1, 10}], n ]]
```

to find the solution you are looking for. Both of these functions **also** have limititations on their capabilities but they can be a good alternative.